# A weird problem happened when parsing a html page using HTMLParser

Tags: java, html, parsing

I was parsing a web page using HTMLParser in Java, I met a weird problem when using class `HasAttributeFilter`.

The element I wanna parse in the page is `<span style="vertical-align: middle;"></span>`, so the expression should be `HasAttributeFilter filter = new HasAttributeFilter("style", "vertical-align: middle;");`, right? Yeah, I used this exp, but it **DIDN'T WORK**! BUT I am sure there IS the node in the page

After that, I applied some other exp, such as `HasAttributeFilter filter = new HasAttributeFilter("class", "singlecolumnminwidth");` to the same page, and also, the node is there, something weird happened, this expression **WORKED**!

Has anyone met this problem before? Help me ...
Thanks in advance!

The page's [link](http://www.amazon.cn/%E6%8C%AA%E5%A8%81%E7%9A%84%E6%A3%AE%E6%9E%97-%E6%9D%91%E4%B8%8A%E6%98%A5%E6%A0%91/dp/B0011F9UUO/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1305389060&sr=8-1).

Comment: Can you post a code snippet? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the span tag is not added dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

what do you get if you fetch the value of this attribue and print it out to the screen?

do you maybe have to escape some chars like space or minus?  think it could have problems with the space in between

does vertical-align:middle; work?
or maybe test if its the minus causing an error

Comment: 1 I didn't parse the value, after parsing, you can get a **NodeList**,I just printed the size of the list(the number of the elements that the parser parsed, I got the correct number for the 1st statement, 0 for the 2nd)

Comment: 2 don't need to escape any char(except for some chars like quote), I put the same attribute and value to another HTML, and parsed it, "vertical-align: middle;" **worked**.  -_-b I don't know what happened and how to explain that, it's just like a ghost.

Comment: String url1 = "http://www.amazon.cn/挪威的森林-村上春树/dp/B0011F9UUO/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1305389060&sr=8-1";
NodeFilter nf_span = new TagNameFilter("span");
NodeFilter nf_comm_title = new AndFilter(nf_span, new HasAttributeFilter("style", "vertical-align: middle;"));
HasAttributeFilter nf_attri = new HasAttributeFilter("style", "vertical-align: middle;");
NodeFilter nf_attri1 = new HasAttributeFilter("id", "ap_container");
Parser parser = new Parser(url1);
parser.setEncoding("UTF-8");
NodeList titlelist = parser.parse(nf_attri1);
System.out.println(titlelist.size());

Comment: should there be a value in the span lik <pan>value</span>? think it has problems with empty tags